# LNK2019 error, trying to override operator<< for LinkedList class

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

I've declared my operator<< in the LinkedList class:

```
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, LinkedList<Type>& list);
```

and defined it:

```
template <class Type>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, LinkedList<Type>& list) {
    s << "[";
    LinkedList<Type>* t = list;
    while (*t._next != NULL) {
        s << *t._info;
        *t = *t._next;
        if (*t._next != NULL) {
            s << ", ";
        };
    };
    s << "]";
    return s;
}
```

and whenever I try to call it:

```
LinkedList<int>* list = new LinkedList<int>();
list.add(<some int>);
cout << *list << endl;
```

it throws the LNK2019 error when I try to compile.

If I try it without the asterisk it simply outputs the address that list points to. I've looked at other questions regarding operator<< and the most common answer is that the function isn't actually defined anywhere.

Comment: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting from references to pointers you must the address of operator(`&`). Also when dealing with pointers, it is better to use the `->` operator as the `.` operator takes precedence over the `*` operator. This code should work:

```
template <class Type>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& s, LinkedList<Type>& list) {
    s << "[";
    LinkedList<Type> * t = &list;
    while (t->_next != NULL) {
        s << t->_info;
        t = t->_next;
        if (t->_next != NULL) {
            s << ", ";
        };
    };
    s << "]";
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This combined with defining the function inside the class declaration worked, but I had to write a getInfo() function as this was simply outputting the address of the _info.